# In R, replace rowvalues based on colname matching rowname in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, replace, matching, r-rownames

I want R to replace rows with NA values if the column name matches the row name of another column. For instance, if individual 123 was last registered in array 6 (Very.last=Last.6), it will replace the time in Last.6 with NAs.

E.g. Before

| ID | Last.5 | Last.6 | Very.last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-04 | Last.8 |
| 124 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-15 | Last.6 |

After replacing its last registrations with NA:

| ID | Last.5 | Last.6 | Very.last |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-04 | Last.8 |
| 123 | 2021-04-01 | NA | Last.6 |

Any suggestions?

Have tried using `dplyr::filter`, but not sure how to filter based on the row name matching a column name for a certain individual.

Comment: Why have the colnames changed in the second df?

Comment: Sorry - posted it a bit soon; its just example data, so the second df is supposed to be the same as the first, except with NA in Last.6 for ID 124

Answer (score 1):

Use `cur_column()` within `dplyr::across()` to test each column name against `Very.last`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(
    Last.1:Last.4,
    ~ if_else(cur_column() == Very.last, NA_real_, .x)
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
     ID Last.1 Last.2 Last.3 Last.4 Very.last
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    
1   121  7.10    9.62  8.73   NA    Last.4   
2   122  2.46   NA     0.411   5.66 Last.2   
3   123 NA       5.74  6.61    5.94 Last.1   
4   124  0.914   7.64 NA       3.65 Last.3
```

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

dat <- tibble::tibble(ID = 121:124)

for (i in 1:4) {
  dat[[paste0("Last.", i)]] <- runif(4, 0, 10)
}

dat[["Very.last"]] <- paste0("Last.", sample(4))
```

Comment: I tried running this but got error: "Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Last.left.A1`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must have class `numeric`, not class `POSIXct/POSIXt`."
I suspect it is checking the rows of columns Last.1:Last.9, instead of checking their column names against the rownames of very.last. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: `if_else()` is very strict about vectors being the same class, including `NA`s. Try replacing `NA_real_` with `as.POSIXct(NA)`.

Comment: I still get error: "Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Last.left.A1`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be a double vector, not a character vector."
However, my rows within Last.left are time posixct variables; but I only want the column names of "Last.left.." to be checked against the rownames of "Very.last"; in that case the posixct should not be an issue as both colname (of last.left) and rownames in very.last are characters?

Comment: I’d need to see your data and code to help more. Please edit your original question to include a sample of your data (use `dput()`), your code, and the error. Or you could post it as a new question.